# Django - get value from calculated Field in model / unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'unicode' and 'int'

Tags: python, django

I'm new to  django and python.

In my queryset I added an calculated field (bmi) which ist comes from DecimalFields(weight(kg) and height(cm)) of an entry(person).
If trying out in the shell it all works fine. It shows the value after "new.bmi" or print "new.bmi"

In my project it raises an error:
unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'unicode' and 'int'

I don't actually want unicode or int because i would like to give the value as decimal or float to another function. But trying to convert it by str(), unicode(), float() or Decimal() does not work.

trying with: 
`new = Eintrag.objects.filter(pk=1).values('bmi')[0]` does not work because I cannot access calculated fields with values()

Thank you for your help!

Here the relevant passages of my files:

models.py - class person

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
weight = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=3)
height = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=3)
    def _get_bmi(self):
        bmi_r = Decimal(self.weight) / Decimal(self.height/100) / Decimal(self.height/100)
        return Decimal(bmi_r)

bmi = property(_get_bmi)
```

view.py
...

```
new = person.objects.get(pk=1)
print new.bmi     #same problem with: print Decimal(new.bmi) // print float(new.bmi) // str(new.bmi) // unicode(new.bmi)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just a matter of putting the division in the right place:

```
bmi_r = Decimal(self.weight) / (Decimal(self.height)/100) / (Decimal(self.height)/100)
```

`Decimal` takes a string and converts it into a number. You were trying to do the division *before* the conversion.

Comment: The following does not work for my either (same error message): bmi_r = ((self.weight) / (self.height/100) / (self.height/100))
            return Decimal(bmi_r)

Comment: @Tiehscher how does that resemble anything I put into my answer?

Comment: @Tiehscher looking again at the question I think the problem is that `self.weight` and `self.height` are not being assigned as you think they are. Try printing `repr(self.weight)` and `repr(self.height)` for debugging purposes.

Comment: Sorry! It already solved my problem. Perfect and fast! Misunderstood your answer. Thank you